# module 'keras.api._v2.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'legacy'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

On using

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.003, decay=  0.0001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=opt)
```

### I get the error:

```
AttributeError  
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-d91f2f0e1042> in <module>
----> 1 opt = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.003, decay=  0.0001)
      2 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=opt)

AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'legacy'
```

how to solve the above problem ??

Comment: Remove `.legacy` from your code. `Adam` works on its own.

Comment: Replace `opt = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.003, decay=  0.0001)` with `opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003, decay=  0.0001)`